# Sci-fi series soldier in goes to sleep and awakes in future

Tags: story-identification, time-travel

Ex soldier sent by government to future with his wolf pet,  nothing left for him,  wife and child killed, has sex before he leaves and she has a child, when he awakes he's in the distant future and makes contact with his family.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Great start. Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and see if you can edit in any more details.

Comment: And who did he have sex with? His wife is dead before he leaves as I understand it, as well as a prior child.

Comment: Is this a book? Film? Comic? TV series? When did you read/watch it? Do you know roughly when it was created?